# Get a two, this values in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

After pressing on a `div`, I want to get two `values` from other divs from another div `id`, but the `console` pops up such a mistake:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.

How can I get two values but this `div` I will press (not all div)?

**JS:**

```
$(".addtobasket").on("click", function (evt) {
    $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var suma = 0;
    var przedmiot = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var nazwa = $("#"+przedmiot+" .nazwa").text();
    var cena = $("#"+przedmiot+" .cenaprzedmiotu").text();
    var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>"+nazwa+"</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>"+cena+" zł</span></li>";

    $("#koszyk").append(li);

    $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function()
    {
        suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

    $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
});
```

**HTML/PHP:**

```
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $i++;
            echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\">

            <section class='produkt' id='$i' draggable='true'>";

            echo "<div class=\"opis\">
                <div class=\"nazwa\" style='margin-top:6px;'>".$row['nazwa']."</div>
                <div><b>Cena:</b> <span class=\"cenaprzedmiotu\">".$row['cena']."</span> PLN</div>
                <div id='kategoriaproduktu' style='display: none;'>".$row['kategoria']."</div>
            </div><div class='addtobasket'><i class=\"fas fa-cart-plus\"></i></div>";

            echo "</section></div>";
        }
```

Comment: Please, Explain what's your problem? And, what's the expected result?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? The message is pretty clear....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear, but from what I understand of it, I believe the following should fix your issue.

Because ".addtobasket" is being added after page loads, you cannot directly assign a click function to it from the start.

Change:

```
$(".addtobasket").on("click", function (evt) {

}
```

to:

```
$("body").on("click", ".addtobasket", function (evt) {

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it did not solve my problem. there is still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What should `evt.dataTransfer` contain? According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer), that is set during a drag and drop operation. Try to use `evt.target` instead